# Firefox addon ignore iframes

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to build an addon for LinkedIn but the contentscript is outputted in every frame...

My main.js:

```
exports.main = function() {

  var pageMod = require("page-mod");

  pageMod.PageMod({
    include: "http://www.linkedin.com/*",
    contentScriptWhen: 'ready',
    contentScript: 'alert("test")'
  });
};
```

by doing a check for frame elements i can do an action if its the top frame

```
if(window.frameElement === null){ alert("YEAH this is the right place!); }
```

But my content srcipt is complex and uses jquery, and this script still puts the script in every frame...

Comment: The Add-on SDK doesn't distinguish between top-level documents and frames. So it is either your approach or maybe the URL of the frames is different enough that you can filter them out in your `include` parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE, the SDK's page-mod api now supports 'attachTo', so you can do this instead:

```
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var page = require('sdk/page-mod');

page.PageMod({
     match:['*'],
     contentScriptOptions: {},
     contentScriptFile: [data.url('myScript.js')],
     attachTo: 'top',
     onAttach: function(worker) {
         //set up hooks or other background behavior
     },
});
```

See [this more recent question for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26149431/how-do-i-prevent-firefox-sdk-content-scripts-from-loading-multiple-times).

<del>There are two approaches you could look into:</del>

<del>1. attach your content scripts using the tabs module. This works because the tabs module only deals with top-level documents. Here is a simple example:</del>

<del>https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/package/22176/latest/</del>

<del>2. do an initial load of a very small content script via page-mod, and then if thepage is something you really want to mod, inject scripts by sending them via port.emit messages. There is an example of this sort of scheme from the dotjs add-on:</del>

<del>https://github.com/rlr/dotjs-addon</del>