# How do I prevent Firefox SDK content scripts from loading multiple times?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-sdk

How do I prevent Firefox SDK content scripts from loading multiple times? The docs and a bug report I found suggest the `contentScriptWhen` property should limit the number of times my content scripts are executed, yet I see them running anywhere from twice to 15 times in a page load.

Here's what's in my main.js:

```
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var tabs = require('sdk/tabs');

var pageMod = require('sdk/page-mod');
pageMod.PageMod({
    include: ['*'],
    contentScriptWhen: "ready",
    contentScriptFile: [data.url("extBootstrapper.js"), data.url("extContent.js")],
    onAttach: function(worker) {
       //handlers for AJAX and changing preferences, etc
       ...
});
```

I've tried controlling this behavior with the `contentScriptWhen` property, as well as by having an 'isLoaded' flag on each script - neither prevents the scripts from executing multiple times.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PageMod attaching worker to same URL multiple times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22382201/pagemod-attaching-worker-to-same-url-multiple-times)

Comment: Although your answer works, if you'd like to keep using a `PageMod`, check the top of the question I've just posted as a duplicate. Namely, simply add `attachTo: 'top'` in your `PageMod` constructor.

Comment: Also note that `contentScriptWhen: "ready"` is the default behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this was a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23585352/why-this-contentscript-runs-various-times-in-a-firefox-add-on/26151761#26151761), which, naturally, only turned up in search results a couple of hours after I had posted its duplicate. Go figure.

It lead me to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002542/firefox-addon-ignore-iframes) in which the author was attempting to prevent his addon from running in iFrames. Eureka! Turns out my addon wasn't "initializing" multiple times for the same page, but `page-mod` doesn't make distinctions between pages and iFrames.

The solution I used was to use the tabs API to inject my content onto the page, like so:

```
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var tabs = require('sdk/tabs');

tabs.on('ready', function(tab) {
     var worker = tab.attach({
          contentScriptOptions: {},
          contentScriptFile: [data.url('myScript.js')]
     });

     // now set up your hooks:        
     worker.port.on('someKey', function(data) {
          //do whatever with your data
     });

});
```

Turns out [another version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22382201/pagemod-attaching-worker-to-same-url-multiple-times) of this question also existed, in which the `attachTo` property is used to specify that pageMod.onAttach should only be fired on the top window, rather than iframes:

```
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var page = require('sdk/page-mod');

page.PageMod({
     match:['*'],
     contentScriptOptions: {},
     contentScriptFile: [data.url('myScript.js')],
     attachTo: 'top',
     onAttach: function(worker) {
         //set up hooks or other background behavior
     },
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering - I updated the older answer to reflect the existence of attachTo.